# JavaScript Console Game Point System

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started programming, and I am making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I am trying to implement a point system for the player. The game is played in the console, but I am getting "SyntaxError: return not in function" whenever I run it. If I remove the return statement, the score stays at 0 even when the player wins.

How can I get it to add a point whenever the if statement is true?

```
for (let playerPoints = 0; playerPoints < 5; playRound()){
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();
    let playerSelection = playerPlay();

    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

    if (playRound == "You Win! Rock Beats Scissors" || playRound == "You Win! Paper Beats Rock" || playRound == "You Win! Scissors Beats Paper"){
       return playerPoints += 1;
    }

    console.log("Player Points: " + playerPoints);
}
```

Comment: Try removing the return and simply increment the variable for the player points in your conditional

Comment: `playRound` is a function, so the `if` condition will always be false. You'll want to assign the result of the function call to a variable, and then use that variable in your `if` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call return from within a function.
You will also need to store the return value of the playRound(...) call.
Currently, your if statement only checks if the function 'playRound' is equal to a string.

Try using the following:

```
for (let playerPoints = 0; playerPoints < 5;){
    let computerSelection = computerPlay();
    let playerSelection = playerPlay();

    let result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    console.log(result);

    if (result == "You Win! Rock Beats Scissors" || result == "You Win! Paper Beats Rock" || result == "You Win! Scissors Beats Paper"){
       playerPoints++;//increase player points by one, no return needed
    }

    console.log("Player Points: " + playerPoints);
}
```